# Библиотека для работы с MS SQL ReportingServices (SSRS)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, ssrs

Коллеги! Подскажите библиотеку для работы SSRS API. Я пытаюсь из WebApi сделать запрос к серверу отчётов и запросить какой либо отчёт. Делаю запрос через HttpClient, но если я не ошибаюсь существуют готовые библиотеки для работы с сервисом отчётов, и получения их в C# коде. Сейчас для получения ответа от сервиса приходится сочинять свои классы - модели.

Comment: Библиотека Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms asp-компонент `ReportViewer`.

Comment: @nick_n_a, скажитеподойдёт ли она мне, если я не использую WebForms? У меня WebApi.

Comment: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms - такого nuget пакета не нашёл...

Comment: Нужно просто получить список всех отчётов, какое апи мне может в этом помочь?

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms153697(v=sql.120).aspx) для SQL Server 2014 необходимо использовать библиотеки `Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportExecution2010`, `Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010` и `Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`. В частности, `Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010` содержит метод `ListChildren`, который возвращает список отчётов, содержащихся в указанной папке.

Получить класс ReportExecution2010.ReportExecutionService Вы можете из wsdl-описания веб-сервиса Вашего сервера отчётов по адресу `http://<сервер>/<экземпляр reporting service>/ReportExecution2010.asmx?wsdl`

Для формирования отчёта алгоритм следующий:

1. Получить шаблон отчёта с сервера с помощью `ReportExecution2005.LoadReport(string Report, string HistoryID)`
2. Подготовить список параметров для отчёта в формате `ReportExec2005.ParameterValue[]`
3. Установить параметры шаблону отчёта с помощью `ReportExec2005.SetExecutionParameters(ParameterValue[] Parameters, string ParameterLanguage)`
4. Получить массив байт с результатом подготовки отчёта с помощью `ReportExec2005.Render(string Format, string DeviceInfo, out string Extension, out string MimeType, out string Encoding, out Warning[] Warnings, out string[] StreamIds)`. Если Вы хотите получить отчёт в *.pdf, то значение `Format` должно быть `PDF`.

Comment: использую SQL Server 2014, какую библиотеку можно использовать в моём случае? И как её установить?

Comment: Как можно получить конкретный отчёт, например в PDF?

Comment: делаю так http://localhost:90/reportserver/ReportExecution2010.asmx?wsdl Ответ: Ошибка служб Reporting Services
Недопустимый путь к элементу "wsdl". Путь должен содержать менее 260 символов. Применяются и другие ограничения. Если сервер отчетов работает в собственном режиме, путь должен начинаться с символа косой черты ("\"). (rsInvalidItemPath) Вызов справки в сети
SQL Server Reporting Services

Comment: что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вот здесь подробно описано, как получить wsdl-файл: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/reporting-services/report-server-web-service/methods/report-server-web-service-endpoints

Comment: по запросу http://localhost:90/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx?wsdl получил большой xml файл, что с ним делать дальше, по ссылке не нашёл шаги

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb628649.aspx